# Show only selected Fields on swagger

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, swagger

I have a DTO called PriceConfigDTO, it has multiple relationships with another entities and those appear in the Swagger examples as a full tree referencing another entities.

However, I only want these examples to have the ID of the objects they relate to. Like:

```
{
      "value": 0,
      "priceType": "WHOLESALE",
      "taxesConfigIds": [
        "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
      ],
      "itemPricingConfig": {
        "id": "itemprincingconfig_id"
      }
      "priceConfigHistory": [
         {
             "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
         }
      ]
}
```

But in Swagger they appear as:

```
    {
  "value": 0,
  "priceType": "WHOLESALE",
  "taxesConfigIds": [
    "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
  ],
  "itemPricingConfig": {
    "unityType": "USER",
    "minimumQuantity": 0,
    "maximumQuantity": 0,
    "createdAt": "string",
    "updatedAt": "string",
    "fixedQuantity": true,
    "billingConfigId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "setupFee": true,
    "prices": [
      null
    ],
    "itemConfig": {
      "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "name": "string",
      "logo": {
        "url": "string",
        "type": "LOGO",
        "width": 0,
        "length": 0,
        "createdAt": "string",
        "updatedAt": "string",
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
      },
      "item": {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "createdAt": "string",
        "updatedAt": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "description": "string",
        "partNumber": "string",
        "categories": [
          {
            "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
          }
        ],
        "itemConfigs": [
          null
        ],
        "enabled": true,
        "itemStatus": "SAVED",
        "vendor": "string"
      },
      "description": "string",
      "createdAt": "string",
      "updatedAt": "string",
      "itemTechConfig": [
        {
          "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
          "requirement": "string",
          "integrationAdapterId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
          "subscriptionType": "RECURRING",
          "createdAt": "string",
          "updateddAt": "string"
        }
      ],
      "itemPricingConfig": [
        null
      ],
      "image": {
        "url": "string",
        "type": "LOGO",
        "width": 0,
        "length": 0,
        "createdAt": "string",
        "updatedAt": "string",
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
      }
    },
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
  },
  "priceConfigHistory": [
    {
      "event": "CREATE",
      "description": "string",
      "createdAt": "string",
      "updatedAt": "string",
      "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "string",
  "updatedAt": "string",
  "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}
```

I have tried using multiple notations such as @JsonIgnore and @JsonIncludeProperties but it does not work since it still shows in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden attribute of @ApiModelProperty

https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#hidden()

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work since if I use this notation in the nested class' fields, it won't show it in the nested class' example.
Using this in the class field itself doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonIncludeProperties` doesn't seem to be respected by Swagger so far. You could go the other way around and use a black list with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on nested properties. However, this is not as convenient as to use `@JsonIncludeProperties` and I hope this gets implemented some time.